# Show number of exact duplicate votes for each URL

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

For the rare cases where a question is in the process of getting closed as a duplicate of more than one other question, can the close summary dialog show the current votes? It does so in parentheses before you've voted (when you select "exact duplicate"), but you can't see the breakdown anymore after you vote. Something like this:

[image: Modified close reasons dialog with the addition described above]